# alterar valor contant global

Tags: android, constantes

Boa tarde,

gostaria saber se é possivel alterar o valor recebido por uma constante global e setar outro valor.
Por exemplo, eu pego o valor da cor que esta setado nas configurações da edge lighting dos aparelhos samsung, e quero que o meu app envie uma nova cor para isso.

```
public class EdgeLightingSettings {

    public static final class Global {
        public static final String EDGELIGHTING_CUSTOM_COLOR = "edgelighting_custom_color";


    }
}
```

Aqui eu pego o valor que esta customizado pelo usuario na configuração nativa da tela edge. quero mudar isso no codigo.

Tem jeito? O.o

Answer (score 0):

Por definição da linguagem, qualquer **constante** (que no java é representado pelo modificador `final`) não pode ser alterado.

Se você quiser um valor global, mas que possa ser alterado, você deve remover o modificador `final` e manter apenas o modificador `static`. No seu caso, ficaria:

```
public class EdgeLightingSettings {

    public static class Global {
        public static String EDGELIGHTING_CUSTOM_COLOR = "edgelighting_custom_color";
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira, você poderia alterar o valor de `EDGELIGHTING_CUSTOM_COLOR` chamando:

```
Global.EDGELIGHTING_CUSTOM_COLOR = "Seu valor";
```

Comment: Olá @regmoraes, obrigado por responder. No caso eu precisava de pegar o valor que é retornado dessa variavel e alterar. Por exemplo, a variavel retorna uma cor em int -25751485, e eu gostaria de alterar esse valor de int, fazer mudar a cor de onde essa constante esta vindo. Não sei se consegui te explicar bem o que eu queria hehe...obrigado